# ImportError: cannot import name '_assert_no_grad' from 'torch.nn.modules.loss'

Tags: python, pytorch, python-import, torch, torchvision

Installed PyTorch using `pip install torchvision`

Trying to import  `_assert_no_grad` and `_Loss using`

> from torch.nn.modules.loss import _assert_no_grad, _Loss using

Getting this error even after reinstalling the Torch and PyTorch

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ubuntu/Project/Segmentation/pytorch-discriminative-loss/src/loss.py",
> line 7, in 
> from torch.nn.modules.loss import _assert_no_grad, _Loss ImportError: cannot import name '_assert_no_grad' from
> 'torch.nn.modules.loss'
> (/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py)

N. B. - torch version = 1.7.0 and torchvision = 0.8.1

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/8460

Comment: if the issue is already merged then why the updated version is not working?

Comment: Doesn't it say that `_assert_no_grad` has been removed?